# Update column values in backend module of yii2 advanced template

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm using php yii2 advanced template for my web application and have an `User Management` module. I would like to update all the users whose status `inactive` to `active` . Is there any way in which I can do that using the admin module or

[image]

[image]

Comment: What about a custom button and an additional function in the controller? Where did you get this admin view with dark menu on the left side, it looks nice?

Comment: @Perino thanks perino. Will have a look into that. Regarding the theme, I'm just started working on exisiting code. so not sure where did they get from.

Comment: you can have a custom button if you want to update all the users once otherwise, you can have the dropdown in every row in the status column through which you can update the status individually by changing the dropdown option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a custom button into your view, something like that:

```
<?= Html::a('Update', ['update_all'], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
```

And in the related controller a function like:

```
public function actionUpdate_all()
{
    .....
}
```